# get magento product image description

Tags: magento

using this code i am able to find out the list of image for a particular product

```
       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
            foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
                 echo var_export($image->getUrl());
            }
```

but i want to know that which is image is `Base Image` and which is `Thumbnail`

what changes do i need to do in this code???

Answer (score 0):

Media Gallery Images are all types of product media images that are not excluded.

As you are asking "get magento product description"  in the thread title i would say:

```
$image->getLabelDefault()
```

As far as i know/see there is no image type information like thumbnail e.g. in the $image-object. Maybe you see something that i have missed in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`, but 
as i told you, you just get images for the gallery - which are not excluded, so it doesnt matter, of what image media type they are (thumbnail, small_image etc...)

Hope this helps at least a little bit...good luck!